# Android emulator not started. always throwing error for browserName while not include in caps

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, appium, saucelabs, appium-android

I am trying to automate appium android but the desired capability always throw error for sauce labs like:

> Unable to parse remote response: Cannot specify both browserName and
>   app caps.

I haven't add browserName in cap still it is showing key in request JSON

I have also upload apk on server using curl command

Full error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:
>   Unable to parse remote response: Cannot specify both browserName and
>   app caps. Please check our platforms configurator
>   (https://wiki.saucelabs.com/display/DOCS/Platform+Configurator):
>   {'deviceName': 'Android Emulator', 'app':
>   'sauce-storage:HelloGappium-android.zip', 'platform': 'ANDROID',
>   'browserName': 'chrome', 'version': '', 'deviceType': 'phone',
>   'deviceOrientation': 'portrait', 'platformVersion': '4.4',
>   'platformName': 'Android', 'appiumVersion': '1.5.1'}  Build info:
>   version: '3.7.1', revision: '8a0099a', time:
>   '2017-11-06T21:01:39.354Z'  System info: host: '', ip:
>   '', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version:
>   '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_131'  Driver info: driver.version:
>   AndroidDriver  at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:111)
>   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:73)
>   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:142)
>   at
>   io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:89)
>   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:600)
>   at
>   io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
>   at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)  at
>   io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
>   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:219)
>   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:142)
>   at
>   io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:38)
>   at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:83)  at
>   io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:93)  at
>   io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.(AndroidDriver.java:72)
>   at
>   test.java.sauceLabs.HybridBaseSauceLabs.capabilities(HybridBaseSauceLabs.java:37)
>   at
>   test.java.sauceLabs.HybridBasetestcase.main(HybridBasetestcase.java:26)

My code:

```
public static AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> capabilities() throws MalformedURLException 
{

DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.android(); 
caps.setCapability("appiumVersion", "1.5.1"); 
caps.setCapability("deviceName","Android Emulator"); 
caps.setCapability("deviceType","phone"); 
caps.setCapability("deviceOrientation", "portrait"); 
caps.setCapability("platformVersion", "4.4"); 
caps.setCapability("platformName","Android"); 
caps.setCapability("app","sauce-storage:HelloGappium-android.zip");

driver = new AndroidDriver<>(new URL(URL), caps); 

return driver; 
}
```

[image]

Please let me know if I am missing anything as I am new to sauce labs

Please share your working caps for sauce labs specific to android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://wiki.saucelabs.com/display/DOCS/Platform+Configurator#/) you can find the platform configurator. Sauce Labs supply it to help with getting the right caps which is what you need. Based on your configuration, the correct caps will look like this for **web** testing:

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.android();
caps.setCapability("appiumVersion", "1.6.4");
caps.setCapability("deviceName","Android Emulator");
caps.setCapability("deviceOrientation", "portrait");
caps.setCapability("browserName", "Browser");
caps.setCapability("platformVersion", "4.4");
caps.setCapability("platformName","Android");
```

for **Hybrid** or **App** testing, the `browserName` will be set as:

```
caps.setCapability("browserName", "");
```

Comment: Thanks Eugene for you reply .. what is aps .. it a reference variable of which object .. caps itself?

Comment: @ShubhamJain oops, fixed typo

Comment: But you havn't set the app for hybrid app and error is denoting same that we can't use browserName and app together

Comment: I have tried your code but still showing same error. do I need to remove app cap .. if yes then how sauce get to know which hybrid apk I am pointing out for execution

Comment: for Hybrid app, the `browserName` should be set like this. Empty string. It probably defaults to Chrome if you do not set it at all. This is why you see this in log.

Comment: Thanks mate, It's working now ... I missed that part .. thanks for helping